# String interpolation in HTML attributes in an ERB file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have an attribute that looks like this:

```
 data-text = "I won ### by playing..."
```

Where ### should be a value that I have in @credits.

How am I supposed to place that there?

I am having the same trouble when trying to do:

```
data-url = <%= request.scheme %> + "//" + <%= request.port %>
```

In this case I don't know how to place the "" that should be surrounding the whole scheme + port.

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
data-text = "I won #{@credits} by playing..."
```

You can apply the same principle for the other string, like so:

```
data-url = "#{request.scheme}//#{request.port}"
```

Comment: Just a note `data-url` is not a valid variable name. When you attempt to assign anything to it you get the following: `undefined local variable or method data for main:Object`

Comment: @andy, that would be the case if we were not inside an `html` environment where `data-url` is valid.

Comment: I think you mean, `data-url = "<%= request.scheme %>//<%= request.port %>"` since it is erb.

Comment: @LuísRamalho Woops, I apologise. I thought your post was in ruby. `data-url` isn't a valid variable :p But it just occurred to me that the OP was talking about `data-*` tags!

Answer (score 14):

When you have an ERB file, the `"` only interacts with the Ruby inside `<% %>` tags. Outside them, it is ignored by Ruby.

```
<html>
  <tag data-text = "I won <%= @credits %> by playing..." 
       data-url = "<%= request.scheme %>//<%= request.port %>"></tag>
</html>
```

Will produce, depending on your values for those variables:

```
<html>
  <tag data-text = "I won 42 by playing..."
        data-url = "example//3000"></tag>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

I know Charles's solution works because I used that before, and Luis' solution may work as well though I myself have not used that style before.

However there is a much cleaner solution instead of ugly hardcoded html codes. They are tags helpers and link helpers.

See how clean they are when handling data attributes:

```
link_to "homepage", root_path, data: { text: "I won #{@credit}" }

content_tag "div", data: {url: "#{request.scheme}//#{request.port}"}
```

Answer (score 2):

### tag.attributes (Rails 7+)

Starting from Rails 7 there is a new convenient helper [tag.attributes](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40657) which allow generating HTML tag attributes like so:

```html
<html>
<body>
  <tag
    <%= tag.attributes(
      data: {
        text: "I won #{@credits} by playing...",
        url: "#{request.scheme}//#{request.port}"
      }
    ) %>
  >
  </tag>
</body>
</html>
```

More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40657/files#diff-5b7995ab0ade1e7e112ff047b2922ea64eb135f40295a32d1635c0eae0e7bc25R394).

**Sources:**

- [Pull Request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40657).
- [Source Code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/tag_helper.rb#L59).